# append in DataFrame python

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen in other posts that .append in pandas doesnt exist anymore. But I now dont know how to add new lines to an already existing .csv

I create a dictionary where I add the values of each column for then adding it to the csv, the thing is I havent been able to add it. I tried .appen and .concat. I dont know what else to try. Help

```
nuevos= pd.DataFrame(nuevos_datos)
datos_originales = pd.read_csv('datos_carreras.csv')
datos_actualizados = datos_originales.concat(nuevos)
```

nuevos_datos is the dictionary
and datos_originales is the already existing csv